# Why is this equation off?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following equation to calculate some stuff:

```
int stat = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)(((IV + 2 * BaseStat + Math.Floor((double)(EV / 4))) * Level / 100) + 5) * NatureValue));
```

When I use the following values, 15 should be the result.

```
IV = 0  
BaseStat = 28  
EV = 0  
Level = 23  
NatureValue = 0.9
```

The result that comes out is 16.
Am I missing something along the lines of formatting?

Comment: how do you know 15 should be the result?

Comment: Are all your variables double? Otherwise, some of the divisions might be done as integer divisions.

Comment: @klarki Through an other source which calculates the same thing basically.

Comment: pay attention: EV/4 is 0..

Comment: Split you equatation in coule of steps and use debugger.

Comment: @PMF Only NatureValue is a double. The rest are int's.

Comment: @AsfK The code just uses 0 if EV/0 == 0

Comment: @Tony I have no clue which parts can be split up, so I can't really do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is unreadable! Split it in some parts, fix brackets position (I guess there is a mistake) and I guess you should get something like this:

```
var var1 = IV + 2 * BaseStat + Math.Floor((double)(EV / 4)); // 0 + 56 + 0 = 56
var var2 = (double)(var1 * Level / 100) + 5; // 17.88

int stat = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(var2) * NatureValue); // 17*0.9 = 15,3

// here you are! 15
```

Comment: You are welcome! Please remember readability is very very important! It really helps you and others to find mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `Math.Floor((double)EV / 4)` causes the entire expression its in to be evaluated as a `double`:

```
(((IV + 2 * BaseStat + Math.Floor((double)(EV / 4))) * Level / 100) + 5)
```

This computes as

```
(((0 + 2 * 28 + (double)0 ))) * 23 / 100 + 5)
```

which evaluates to 17.88.  17.88 * 0.9 = 16.092, which rounds down to 16.

Comment: So if I remove that cast to double it should be fixed?

Comment: No, because `Math.Floor` itself _returns_ a `double`.  If you want the divide by 100 to truncate a particular way, the clearest way would be to take `Math.Floor` of the entire division.  The "fewest characters" way would be to cast the result of the `Math.Floor` above back to `int`.  Or, break it up into multiple steps and make it clear what variable type you want in each step.

Comment: `Math.Floor((double)EV / 4)` is not exactly the same as `Math.Floor((double)(EV / 4))`, however in this case, it will return the same result. It could be abbreviated to just `(double)(EV/4)`, though, since an integer division on positive values does an implicit `Floor`.

Comment: @PMF: That's a good point, and highlights a different potential bug in the original code.  It wasn't the bug I was addressing, but is likely a bug nonetheless.  Good catch.